# update tkinter label from serial data whenever there's new data from serial port python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyserial

I have encounter this problem where i could not display any value on the label which i wanted to constantly update it whenever there's new data coming in from the serial port. I'm new to python, really need the help.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM5',\
    baudrate=9600,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=4)

class Menu:

    def __init__(self):    

        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main_window.title("Room Light System")
        self.main_window.geometry("1200x600")


        #Frames
        self.frame_2 = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window, bg='Orange') # Receiving DATAs



        #ReceiveLabel
        self.ReceiveLabel = tkinter.Label(self.frame_2,\
                                       text = 'Received DATAs',\
                                       bg = 'White',\
                                       height = 2, width = 20)


        #Temperature
        self.GetTempLabel = tkinter.Label(self.frame_2,\
                                       text='Temperature :')
        self.TempValue = tkinter.StringVar()

        self.GetTempValueLabel = tkinter.Label(self.frame_2,bg = 'Green',\
                                               textvariable = self.TempValue
                                               )



        #PACKING!!! F2

        self.frame_2.pack()
        self.frame_2.place(x=410, y=0, height=300, width=400)
        #ReceiveLabel
        self.ReceiveLabel.pack()
        self.ReceiveLabel.place(x=100, y=10)
        #Temperature
        self.GetTempLabel.pack()
        self.GetTempLabel.place(x=50, y=80, height=20, width=120)
        self.GetTempValueLabel.pack()
        self.GetTempValueLabel.place(x=200, y=80, height=20, width=50)


        #main loop and quit
        self.quitButton = tkinter.Button(self.main_window,\
                                          text = 'Quit',
                                          command = self.main_window.destroy,\
                                          height = 2, width = 6)
        self.quitButton.pack() 

        self.quitButton.place(x=200, y=500)


        tkinter.mainloop()

    def GetTemp(self):

        data = bytearray()
        while(1):
            readline = ser.read(size=10)
            if len(readline) > 0 : 
                data = readline
                v = memoryview(data)                
                P = v.tobytes() 
                P = P.decode(encoding='UTF-8')
                self.TempValue.set(P)

gui = Menu()
ser.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your `GetTemp()` method in a seperated thread from `_thread` module. The thread is called with the `Tkinter` method `after()`. In following example I substituted your `GetTemp()` with a randomn number generated.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import time
import random
import _thread

class Menu:

    def __init__(self):    

        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main_window.title("Room Light System")
        self.main_window.geometry("1200x600")


        #Frames
        self.frame_2 = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window, bg='Orange') # Receiving DATAs



        #ReceiveLabel
        self.ReceiveLabel = tkinter.Label(self.frame_2,\
                                       text = 'Received DATAs',\
                                       bg = 'White',\
                                       height = 2, width = 20)


        #Temperature
        self.GetTempLabel = tkinter.Label(self.frame_2,\
                                       text='Temperature :')
        self.TempValue = tkinter.StringVar()

        self.GetTempValueLabel = tkinter.Label(self.frame_2,bg = 'Green',\
                                               textvariable = self.TempValue
                                               )



        #PACKING!!! F2

        self.frame_2.pack()
        self.frame_2.place(x=410, y=0, height=300, width=400)
        #ReceiveLabel
        self.ReceiveLabel.pack()
        self.ReceiveLabel.place(x=100, y=10)
        #Temperature
        self.GetTempLabel.pack()
        self.GetTempLabel.place(x=50, y=80, height=20, width=120)
        self.GetTempValueLabel.pack()
        self.GetTempValueLabel.place(x=200, y=80, height=20, width=50)


        #main loop and quit
        self.quitButton = tkinter.Button(self.main_window,\
                                          text = 'Quit',
                                          command = self.main_window.destroy,\
                                          height = 2, width = 6)
        self.quitButton.pack() 

        self.quitButton.place(x=200, y=500)


        self.main_window.after(2000, _thread.start_new_thread, self.GetTemp, ())
        tkinter.mainloop()

    def GetTemp(self):

        while(1):
            value = random.random()
            self.TempValue.set(str(value))
            time.sleep(0.5)

gui = Menu()
```

Comment: Hi, it works for the random generated numbers, but when i use it on the serial port, it still does not show any thing on the label

Comment: I don't know your serial module. Is it http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/ ? I guess you should try to make it working without Tkinter first, and then adopt it to your GUI application.

Answer (score 0):

call serial inside the method..it will work..here is my code for serial using Mr Holger's concept..
this code is tested with Raspberry Pi3 serial port ttyS0 as master and serially connected sensor.....

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import time
import _thread
import serial

class Menu:

    def __init__(self):    

        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main_window.title("Serial Data monitor")
        self.main_window.geometry("1000x600")


        #Frames
        self.frame_2 = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window, bg='Orange') # Receiving DATAs



        #ReceiveLabel
        self.ReceiveLabel = tkinter.Label(self.frame_2,\
                                       text = 'Received DATAs',\
                                       bg = 'White',\
                                       height = 2, width = 20)


        #RPM
        self.GetTempLabel = tkinter.Label(self.frame_2,\
                                       text='RPM :')
        self.TempValue = tkinter.StringVar()

        self.GetTempValueLabel = tkinter.Label(self.frame_2,bg = 'Green',\
                                               textvariable = self.TempValue
                                               )


        #torque
        self.GetTemppLabel = tkinter.Label(self.frame_2,\
                                       text='TORQUE :')
        self.TemppValue = tkinter.StringVar()

        self.GetTemppValueLabel = tkinter.Label(self.frame_2,bg = 'Green',\textvariable = self.TempValue)

PACKING!!! F2

        self.frame_2.pack()
        self.frame_2.place(x=410, y=0, height=300, width=400)
        #ReceiveLabel
        self.ReceiveLabel.pack()
        self.ReceiveLabel.place(x=100, y=10)
        #rpm
        self.GetTempLabel.pack()
        self.GetTempLabel.place(x=50, y=80, height=20, width=80)
        self.GetTempValueLabel.pack()
        self.GetTempValueLabel.place(x=200, y=80, height=20, width=120)

        #torque
        self.GetTemppLabel.pack()
        self.GetTemppLabel.place(x=50, y=120, height=20, width=80)
        self.GetTemppValueLabel.pack()
        self.GetTemppValueLabel.place(x=200, y=120, height=20, width=120)

        #main loop and quit
        self.quitButton = tkinter.Button(self.main_window,\
                                          text = 'Quit',
                                          command = self.main_window.destroy,\
                                          height = 2, width = 6)
        self.quitButton.pack() 

        self.quitButton.place(x=200, y=500)


        self.main_window.after(2000, _thread.start_new_thread, self.GetTemp, ())
        self.main_window.after(4000, _thread.start_new_thread, self.GetTempp, ())
        tkinter.mainloop()

    def GetTemp(self):
        s=serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0',baudrate=9600)
        string='*00T%'
        while True:
            s.write(str.encode(string))
            print(string)
            time.sleep(2)
            if s.inWaiting():
               temp=s.readline(s.inWaiting())
               value=temp.decode('utf-8')
               value=value[5:-1]
    def GetTempp(self):
        s=serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0',baudrate=9600)
        string1='*01T%'
        while True:
            s.write(str.encode(string1))
            print(string1)
            time.sleep(2)
            if s.inWaiting():
               tempp=s.readline(s.inWaiting())
               value1=tempp.decode('utf-8')
               value1=value1[5:-1]
               print(value1)
               self.TemppValue.set(str(value1))
               time.sleep(0.5)



gui = Menu()
```