# How to open the serial port while using serial port tools python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyserial

I have been trying to display the [temperature sensor](https://store.ncd.io/product/industrial-long-range-wireless-temperature-humidity-sensor/) values in python shell which is connected with Arduino(connected to my laptop through USB port)

I am trying to get the values of the serial port using python package serial.tools.list_ports but while using mentioned below code

```
import serial
import json
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as ttk
import serial.tools.list_ports

ard = serial.Serial();
root = ttk.Tk()
root.title("Read Sensor")

B = None
C = None 
ser_dict = {}

# Add a grid
mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S) )
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.pack(pady = 100, padx = 100)

# Create a Tkinter variable
tkvar1 = StringVar(root)
tkvar = StringVar(root)

#Serial Port
a=serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
for w in a:
    print(w.device)
    k = [w.device]
    print(k)
ser_dict = { i for i in k }
print (ser_dict)
val1 = tkvar1.get()
if val1 in ser_dict:
    ard.port = str (ser_dict[val1])
    ard.isOpen()
    if C:
        C.destroy()
        C = ttk.Button(root, text =val1, command = dropCall)
        C.pack()


# Dictionary with options
baud = { '9600','119200','34800'}

#Pop Up desciption
popupMenu1 = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar1, *ser_dict)
Label(mainframe, text="Serial Port").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
popupMenu1.grid(row = 2, column =1)

popupMenu2 = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar, *baud)
Label(mainframe, text="Baudrate").grid(row = 3, column = 1)
popupMenu2.grid(row = 4, column =1)


#Serial Callback Functions
def helloCallBack():
    k = ard.readline().decode('ascii');
    if(len(k)>0):
        print (k);
        size = len(k);
        #print (k[0:size-2]);
        print (size);
        messagebox.showinfo('Message From Arduino',k[0:size-2]+'\n'+str(size))  

#def portCall(*kargs):

   #global C
   #global ser_dict


#baudrate functions
def dropCall(*args):
   global B
   value = tkvar.get()
   ## using a dictionary instead of if statements
   ## to show how dictionaries are used
   baud_dict={'9600':value, '34800':value, '119200':value}
   if value in baud_dict:
      ard.baudrate = int(baud_dict[value])
      if B:
         B.destroy()
      B = ttk.Button(root, text =value, command = helloCallBack)
      B.pack()

#Link Function
tkvar.trace('w', dropCall)
```

I have to face the error in which I am not able to open the serial port.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Misha\Desktop\test\GUItest.py", line 61, in helloCallBack
    k = ard.readline().decode('ascii');
  File "C:\Users\Misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 267, in read
    raise portNotOpenError
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Attempting to use a port that is not open
```

Suggestion on this will be a great help.

Comment: You need `ser.open()`. Relevant [update-tkinter-label-from-serial-data-whenever-theres-new-data-from-serial-port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17464241/7414759)

Comment: HI, thanks for the suggestion but It's Still showing the same error after using "ard.open()".

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show **where** you insert `ser.open()`. Your approach, to mixin **Serial** statements with **Tkinter** statements are **error-prone**. Second, you **don't** have a **main entry point** and **no** `.mainloop()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please find some example code that finds and opens the serial port connection to a device connected to a serial port. This is tested with Python 3.6 under Linux. It should work under Windows, but I have not tested this. I use PID and VID to select the attached device as:

1. There may be several active serial ports.
2. The port name can change when you reconnect your device.
3. It is more robust across different OSs. Windows calls ports 'COMx' and Linux uses 'ttyx'.

The PID and VID of your Arduino may be different than in my example. The script will list the PIDs and VIDs of all connected devices. Alter PID_VARIABLE and VID_VARIABLE to the one for your Arduino.

```
import logging
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports as list_ports
from time import sleep

BAUD =  115200
PID_TARGET = 67
VID_TARGET= 9025
TIMEOUT = 0.1

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')


class SerialPort():
    def __init__(self, pid=PID_TARGET, vid=VID_TARGET, baud=BAUD, timeout=TIMEOUT):
        self.serial_port = self.open_serial_port(pid, vid, baud, timeout)


    def get_serial_data(self, serial_port):
        ''' get serial port data '''
        inWaiting = serial_port.inWaiting()
        read_bytes = serial_port.readline(inWaiting)
        if not read_bytes:
            return
        return read_bytes.decode()


    def get_serial_port(self):
        ''' Return the serial port. '''
        return self.serial_port


    def open_serial_port(self, pid=PID_TARGET, vid=VID_TARGET, baud=BAUD, timeout=TIMEOUT):
        ''' Open a serial connection. '''
        print('looking for attached microbit on a serial port')
        serial_port = serial.Serial(timeout=timeout)
        serial_port.baudrate = baud
        ports = list(list_ports.comports())
        print('scanning ports')
        ports.sort(reverse=True)
        for p in ports:
            print('pid: {} vid: {} device: {}'.format(p.pid, p.vid, p.device))
            if (p.pid == pid) and (p.vid == vid):
                print('found target device pid: {} vid: {} port: {}'.format(
                    p.pid, p.vid, p.device))
                serial_port.port = str(p.device)
        if not serial:
            print('no serial port found')
            return None
        try:
            serial_port.open()
            serial_port.flush()
            print('opened serial port: {}'.format(serial_port.port))
        except Exception as e:
            print('cannot open serial port: {}'.format(e))
            return None
        sleep(0.1)
        return serial_port


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('instatiating SerialPort()')
    serial_port = SerialPort()
    print('finished')
```